# Unit of window.innerWidth

Tags: javascript, width

Following

```
var w = (window.innerWidth - 100px);
```

is not working.

Can someone show me how it works?

Comment: var `innerWidth = window.innerWidth - 100`

Comment: Just remember that when you actually USE that later, add a "px" to the end of it.

Comment: Subtraction can only use numbers. `100px` is not a number, `100` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.innerWidth` returns a number in pixels, so you can just subtract 100 from it:

```
var w = window.innerWidth - 100;
```

Note that this will be negative, if the browser is under 100px in width.